# Retrieving JWT token from AWS Cognito in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC after successful authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I have followed [this tutorial](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/v2/workshops/02696107-09ac-4313-a6cb-3798048b07d7/en-US/9-how-to-authenticate-users-in-my-application) to produce a working Cognito authentication solution for my MVC app. However, I need access to the user's JWT token for further custom authentication permissions. I have learned that the [/oauth2/token endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) returns that token. My use case calls for the `grant_type` to be `authorization_code`, which means that I have to pass a `code` parameter to the endpoint. What value needs to be placed there actually? How do I produce it? Alternatively, is there any other way to retrieve/store the JWT anywhere in the application after a user passes authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the JWT of an authorized user can simply be accessed in the controller as in this solution: [Oauth 2.0 How to access the access token saved in AuthenticationProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561836/oauth-2-0-how-to-access-the-access-token-saved-in-authenticationproperties) , completely allowing us to bypass additional AWS calls.